# Can I initialize a database from a database project?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I have a Visual Studio 2012 Solution containing a SQL Server Database Project. I'm using Entity Framework 6 (Beta 1 currently) in my application.

Is there an initializer that allows me to spin up a database from the Database Project?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it using [DacServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dac.dacservices.aspx), have to bundle the .dacpac with the app but overall it works as expected.

Comment: Is it possible to get the schema differences from the database project and the target database?

Comment: @Gian I haven't tried it myself (`DacPackage.Deploy` automatically updates if desired), but it seems that `DacServices.GenerateDeployScript` does what you want: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh753305.aspx - if not, look at `GenerateCreateScript` and `GenerateDeployReport`